# How to remove empty space when web-scraping?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

can someone please help me with how to remove that empty white space?

How am I able to delete that space in line 6?

[image: screenshot pry]

Comment: Write `.strip` at the end

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Don't post images of your code (or links to images). Instead, post the code itself. It makes much more sense to refer to "line 6" if we can see it.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

**Strip** is the function of String class which helps to remove unwanted space available in the string.

**For Example:**

```
str1 = "     \n Testing String   \n" 
puts str1.strip

Output:
Testing String
```